# How can I edit JS from browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I get, on a page, this simple html/script :

```
<a id="hey" href="#">try</a>

var myvar=false;

$('#hey').click(function () {
    if(myvar)
    {
        alert("Well! You change it!");
    }
});
```

clicking on the link, I won't never get the alert show up! So, how can I edit JS (changing `myvar=true;`) on browser? I use Firebug... I need these details to test a security-side of my own application.

Comment: I think you should include `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>`. Is the `myvar` just global variable and you ask how to change its value? Who should trigger such change? Do you want just change the value during debugging the page code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

first warp with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myvar=false;

$('#hey').click(function () {
    if(myvar==true)
    {
        alert("Well! You change it!");
    }
});
</script>
```

### edit

I readlly think you have a problem somewhere else. ...

take this [code](http://jsbin.com/okifed/edit#javascript,html) and save it in a file.

this is what youll get

[image]

myvar is false ( beginning)

[image]

now set it to true :

[image]

and click and see : 
[image]

Comment: Tried! But if I wrote myvar=true; I still don't see the alert :O

Comment: @markzzz try `if(myvar==true)`. besides that - all should work.

Comment: ? I don't understand what you mean! What I want is thaat, after changing this code, clicking on the link the alert must be showed...

Comment: Seems that I can't do it in a iframe! I think about SOP? :)